# Triangle $ABC$ have two sides of length $8$ and $17$. If $\sin 2A=\sin 2B$, find every possible value for the third side.

Tags: trigonometry

Ok, I know that the third side has to be smaller than the sum of the other two sides, and larger than the difference of the two sides.
But the problem places a limit on the value for the third side.
$2\sin A\cos A-2\sin B\cos B$, I don't see how I could use this.

Comment: Either $2A=2B$ (Isosceles), or $2A=180-2B$ (Right triangle).

Comment: How do you know it's a isosceles, could you show me in algebraic terms?

Comment: All I know 'bout trig is that sin and cos of complementary angles are equal. I learned it from two months now.

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle_theorem . We are in geometry here, I would have a hard time describing a triangle and it's properties in algebraic terms!

Comment: But interpreting sin requires knowledge of trig,

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Do you want me to show that if $\sin x = \sin y$, and $x,y\in <0,\pi>$, then $x=y$ or $x=180-y$?

Comment: Only thing, I want you to explain to me how do you know 2A=2B from sin2A=sin2B. Thanks

Comment: $\sin(\square)=\sin(\triangle)\iff\square=\triangle\text{ or }\square+\triangle=180$ for $\square$ and $\triangle$ between $0$ and $180$.  Now plug in anything (between $0$ and $180$) you want for $\square$ and $\triangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's draw a graph of the sine function:

[image]

Now, the coordinates are in radians, so we might convert the units using $180°=\pi$.  We know that every angle $x$ in a triangle satisfies $0=0°<x<180°=\pi$. If we draw an horizontal line in that interval, we can see that it intersects the sine function at most two times. We are trying to solve $\sin x = \sin y$ for (say) $x$.$x=y$ is an immediate solution. But is there another one?
By using $\sin(a-b)=\sin a\cos b - \cos a\sin b$, we can verify that $\sin x=\sin y=\sin(180°-y)$. So $x=180-y$ is another solution.
But, are those solutions actually different? Yes, except if $x=y=180-y$, or $x=y=90$. Since in the graph we can verify that in fact that is the only solution there (in the *peak*), we have found all solutions.  So if $\sin x=\sin y$ and $0<x,y<180°$, then $x=y$ or $x=180-y$.

Comment: Wait...could you explain a little bit more, how you use that difference formula to get siny=sin(180-y).

Comment: @Valkyrie Just put $a=180,b=y$, and use $\cos180°=-1, \sin180°=0$

Comment: Yes, but it can't just plug in random numbers like 180 for a. Why you use 180

Comment: @Valkyrie We **can** plug random numbers in $a$. You asked me how to use the difference formula $\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b)$ to show $\sin(y)=\sin(180º-y)$, and that's how. Why do I do so? Because the function is symmetric around $90º$

Comment: You are right with the symmetry. Ok so plugging in any number in to the difference formula will get you the equation, right?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by that. I just used an special case that helped to prove what we wanted to prove.

Answer (score 3):

With $\sin 2A=\sin 2B$ you have one of:

- $A=B$, which is an isosceles triangle,
- $2A=180-2B$, meaning $A+B=90$. It follows that $C=90$ so you have a right triangle.

How can you assign the lengths in those 2 cases?